# How to convert string with spaces to integers array?

Tags: c++, string, c++17

I want to convert

```
string x = "13 421 23"
```

To integers array:

```
int y[13, 421, 23];
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `int y[13, 421, 23];` -> `std::vector<int> y{13, 421, 23};`.

Comment: btw `int y[13, 421,23];` is not correct syntax, I think you meant `int y[] = {13,421,23};`

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it to a vector of integers using stringstream:

```
string x = "13 421 23"
stringstream ss(x);

vector<int> v; 
// v.reserve(...) ... if you expect some (larger) number of elems, to save some allocs ..)
int n{};
while (ss >> n) v.push_back(n);
...
// or simpler, which will insert one by one and alloc as needed
std::vector<int> v{ std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>() };

// v.data() gives you an int* if you need to pass to some C-Style API
```

Comment: Finish with `int* y = v.data();`

Comment: `std::vector<int> v{ std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>() };` and lose the loop. Someone else can do it for you.

Comment: @WhozCraig what it does with incorrect input?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The same thing the code in this answer prior to that addition did: stops reading and give you whatever it could get.

Comment: @WhosCraig: thx for the hint. The iterator version is cleaner. The only downside IMO is that one cannot reserve space in advance, which in this example doesn't play role because of small number of elems, but in general could matter.

Comment: i believe you can do that with custom allocator